# C Linux stat() getting atime/mtime with nsec precision

Tags: c, linux, variables, stat

Learning C and I'm trying to get a visual comparison of the variable types and sizes that are returned by `stat()` for the atime/mtime attributes and for the nsec precision values.

I'm running `stat()` on a file and want to get the mtime and mtime nsec values from the returned stat structure and then store these values in separate variables (which I then want to pass to `utimes()`... long story!).
According to http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html#NOTES I can get the value from `st_mtim.tv_nsec` or `st_mtimensec` depending on various OS/build conditions. In my actual program I'll check for both and use whichever is set, or just fallback to the normal second precision of `st_mtime`

What variable type and size do I need to declare in order to store a normal timestamp as returned by `st_mtime`?

What variable type and size do I need to declare to store an nsec value from `st_mtim.tv_nsec` or `st_mtimensec`?
Are these a decimal, including the number of whole seconds of the time? Or do they just return the nsec portion of the time?

Do I need to declare different variable sizes for the nsecs depending on my system's architecture?

And finally, what conversion specifiers do I need for outputting these variables using `printf()`?

Cheers, B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `st_mtime` should be a `time_t`.
2. According to POSIX [`<time.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html#tag_13_76), the type of `tv_nsec` is just `long`.
3. The fields like `st_mtim.tv_nsec` will return the number of nanoseconds.
4. For the `long`, you need `l`; for `time_t`, it is not clearly defined, AFAIK.

Comment: That's brilliant. So how can I access the nsec value from stat() in a portable way? Some platforms provide it in st_mtim.tv_nsec and others provide it in st_mtimensec and some platforms/file systems don't provide nsec resolution at all.

Comment: Sadly, you can't easily code to access the nanosecond timing portably, yet.  You will have to code in somewhat platform specific ways for the immediately foreseeable future.  Note that there are platforms where `time_t` is a 64-bit value; there are (many) others where it is a 32-bit value.  It would be helpful if there was an analogue to (or POSIX extension of) `<inttypes.h>` that provided format macros for all the POSIX types such as `time_t`.  AFAIK, that does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

`st_mtim.tv_nsec` is always in the range [0,999999999]. You need to get the seconds from `tv_sec`. In theory you could multiply seconds by 1000000000 and store them together in a 64-bit value, but it will overflow in a couple hundred years or so.

Comment: The 64 bit value has greater range than `tv_sec` if `time_t` is 32-bit. 2^32 sec ~ 136 yr, 2^64 nsec ~ 585 yr.